# How to use HTML2pdf callback function for applying headers and footers for exported PDF?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

As my ongoing saga continues with exporting HTML into a PDF file using html2pdf, jspdf and html2canvas. I have come across another problem. I got everything to work so far including my page breaks for multi-page documents(used, "html2pdf__page-break" in my html). This current problem is applying headers and footers on every page. I did some research and found a way, but it doesn't seem to work for me an not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. According to what someone did they used a callback function to html2pdf which has a jsPDf object. Played around with this and for some reason it's not getting the jsPDF object, 'pdfObject' in my call back function.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="modal-body" id="printItems">
  <div class="container" id="selectedItems"></div>  
</div>

<button stule="border:none"><span id="downloadActivity" class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" title="download report to PDF" onclick="downloadToPDF()"</span></button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/library/html2pdf.bundle.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
function downloadPDF() {
  
  var opt = 
    {
        margin:1,   
        filename: webPage + dateStamp + '.pdf',
        quality: 0.95,
        image: {type: 'jpeg', quality:1},
        html2canvas: {
            dpi:72,
            useCORS: true,
            letterRendering: true,
            width: 205,
            scale: 0.26,
            getContext: '2d'
        },
        jsPDF: {unit: 'in', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait},
    pdfCallback: pdfCallback
    };
   html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).save()


}



function pdfCallback(pdfObject)
{
    for(var = 1; i <= pdfPageCount; i++)
    {
         pdfObject.setPage(i)
         pdfObject.text('Header Text', 10, 10)
         pdfObject.text('Foooter Text', 10, 200) 
    }

}
```